# jQuery.ajax() gives broken image data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, binary, phantomjs

I'm trying to add an AJAX call via jQuery.ajax() to a page acquired by Phantomjs to download an additional image /myfile.jpg:

```
var result = page.evaluate(function() {

    var out;
    $.ajax({
        'async' : false,
        'url' : '/myfile.jpg',
        'success' : function(data, status, xhr) {
            out = data;
        }
    });
    return out;

});

fs.write('myfile.jpg', result, 'wb');
```

The data seems to be successfully downloaded and saved to local file myfile.jpg but it's a broken image and can't be opened at all.

The file size seems to be correct but I'm not sure. The content opened in Notepad++ text editor is NOT texts but lots of unrecognized characters or bytes.

What a I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Downloading files via AJAX is very flaky at best and a bad idea at worst - especially when dealing with binary file types. You should also remove the `async: false` setting. If you check your console you'll even see a warning from the browser about its use.

Comment: You mention both `.jpg` and `.png` in your question. Are you saving the file in the wrong format at some stage?

Comment: Why not simply `$('img').attr('src', '/myfile.jpg')`?

Comment: "The content opened in Notepad++ text editor is NOT texts but lots of unrecognized characters or bytes" - it's a binary. You open an Image file. What did you expect to get?

Comment: This is confusing, you're downloading a binary image file with ajax, which is ... just wrong, then you say you're opening the file in Notepad++ and it's not text, just *"unrecognized characters or bytes"*, well what did you expect, it's a binary file ?

Comment: THAT is not what you use Ajax for....

Comment: @Turnip, it's just a typo.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, we need to save arbitrary files from Phantomjs webpage. AJAX calls seem to be the only way thus far other than taking screenshots which may look very small for large files.

Comment: @Dekel, If it's binary, why can't it be opened correctly then?

Comment: @kavoir.com in which case I'd suggest you open the image via a `canvas` element and save it through that instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397319/save-canvas-as-jpg-to-desktop

Comment: @Justinas, we need to grab the actual contents of the file.

Comment: @kavoir.com because it's binary...? How would you expect an image to be represented in text?

Comment: It can, but with a program that has abilities to open (and view) binary data, not notepad++ (which is a text editor). You can use any Hex Editor for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs: returning result on async result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631790/nodejs-returning-result-on-async-result)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the canvas solution works but the image saved is tremendously larger than the original. We downloaded a image xxx.jpg that's 27KB but end up being saved to local a 312KB file. This is unacceptable considering we have million of files that need to be saved. What could be the problem?

Comment: Assuming you're using `toDataUrl` then you can provide the quality to save at as the second parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL. If not, then it may be worth starting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `download` function instead.
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download

But, you probably [won't be able](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/362) to download a file if its size more than 7MB.

You can also use PhantomJS with [Download support](https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs/tree/download-support) (By [Vitallium](https://github.com/Vitallium))

Comment: Also: won't be able to download files with CasperJS if there's some cookie-based server authentication.

Comment: Is there any docs regarding how to use the [download support](https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs/tree/download-support)? I guess I have to manually compile the download support version?