# How to pass value from asynchronous function (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

From my code, I want the value in `_status` variable after query and write file from `MongoClient.connect`, but I get `NULL` from `return _status`. How can I pass the value outside the function? Thank you for your answer.

```
function query(domain)
{
        var _status;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                if (err) throw err;
                db.collection("zone").find({"name" : domain}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                        if (!err) {
                                fs.writeFile('/root/'+domain+'.txt', result, function (err) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                });
                                _status = "success";
                        }
                        else {
                                _status = "fail";
                        }
                });
                db.close();
        });
        return _status;
}
```

Comment: You should checkout this Stack Overflow Discussion: <br/>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631790/nodejs-returning-result-on-async-result

Answer (score 1):

You are calling asynchronous functions( MongoClient.connect, .find) inside your function query, and trying to get the result(_status) synchronously. This does not work. You can use a callback based approach or a promise based approach to let the value of _status known to the caller.

Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more on promises.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
function query(domain, callback)
{
    var _status;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.collection("zone").find({"name" : domain}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                fs.writeFile('/root/'+domain+'.txt', result, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                });
                _status = "success";
            }
            else {
                _status = "fail";
            }
            callback(_status);
        });
        db.close();
    });
}

query(domain, (status) => {
    // Synchronous
    // do something
    console.log(status);
});
```